# pyplot - Option to Set Colormap LogNorm

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've been fighting this for hours now. I'm working on writing an user-friendly interface to let and my colleagues easily post-process / analyze test data. So, the function is a glorified plt.scatter() call, but includes many options.

I've been able to dig through the API to find most optional calls outside of the function (e.g. ax.set_xlim). But, I am really struggling with how to optionally put the z-axis / colormap into a LogNorm.

My previous version simply had a billion nested `if` statements, and if z_log was called, then

```
if z_log:
    im = ax1.scatter(temp[x], temp[y1], c=temp[z1], norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(), vmin=z_range[0], vmax=z_range[1], cmap="jet")
```

But, I'm trying to clean this up and avoid a lot of nested if statements (also, everything I add something, the number of function calls doubles, ugh). I have been able to remove most of the colormap stuff from the main function call

```
    if z:
        cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax1, label=z)
        im.set_cmap('jet')
        if z_range:
            im.set_clim(z_range[0], z_range[1])
```

but I cannot get LogNorm working. I am currently trying

```
        if z_log:
            im.set_norm(matplotlib.colors.LogNorm())
```

which gives me an impressively long Traceback.. at one point mentioning division by zero. Normally, I'd say that's a problem for plotting log, but 1) I am filtering the data to exclude any negatives, and 2) if I add the original statement into the function call `...scatter(... norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm()...)` then it works perfectly.

I have tried adding optional arguments for vmin/vmax in the LogNorm call, but nothing working.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:
Pre-defining the normalization method seemed to work, but now I am currently stuck on setting the z-scale range. Based on the comments, I was able to successfully add a flag to enable/disable logarithmic plotting of the colorbar.

I was recommended not to use clim, but to use vlim inside the original scatter() call to set the range. I thought that doing a similar approach, of "pre-filling" the values, and then always including it would work. Code below

```
    # Find colormap min/max range. 
    my_vmin, my_vmax = 0.0, 0.0
    if z:
        my_vmin = temp[z].min
        my_vmin = temp[z].max
        if z_range:
            my_vmin = z_range[0]
            my_vmax = z_range[1]

    if isinstance(y1, list):
        for i in range(len(y1)):
            if z: c = temp[z]
            else: c = colors[i]
            im = ax1.scatter(temp[x], temp[y1[i]], label=y1[i], c=c, norm=my_norm, vmin=my_vmin, vmax=my_vmax)
```

Now, this works great if I actually ask to color the markers by data. However, if I try and use a constant, it complains.

If I remove the vmin/vmax from the function call and rely on set_clim()... it really looks like it behaves per my expectation (i.e. I want both the marker colors and the colorbar to be scaled according to my inputs)... I may do a little more research on clim versus vlim and just claim success

Comment: Couldn't you just add a variable beforehand, `my_norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize()`, `if z_logg: my_norm = matplotlib.colors.LogNorm()`.  And thereafter `ax1.scatter(..., norm=mynorm)`?  Also be careful that your values are strictly positive for `log` to be valid. 
Similarly, start with `cmin=None` and optionally set it to a value before calling `scatter`. Also, note that `cmin`and `vmin` are very different concepts. By the way, ['jet' is rarely an adequate default colormap](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/).

Comment: Oh my, that totally worked... such personal anguish... thank you so much!

Regarding clim... I had looked through the API and only found vmin arguments in the set_clim function. 

I guess your recommendation would be to query min/max values of the data range and preset vmin/vmax so that I can include it in the original call as well? This of course gives the ability to change that range optionally. 

I will do some digging around to understand the difference between cmin and vmin. Thanks again